# Google Map not displaying in file called to webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a site which has a footer that contains a Google Map. On the homepage the footer is coded on the page and displays just fine: http://www.clickityclick.me/morehampton/index.html

However, in all the other pages I call the footer from an external file using jquery like this:

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $('#header').load('header_contact.html')
        $('#fatFooter').load('footer.html')
        $('#rightNav').load('rightNav.html')
    });
</script>
```

On the pages where the footer is loaded like this, the map does not display every time - only occasionally.

Am I missing something simple that is causing the map to not display correctly every time a page is loaded? I do not want to have to code the footer onto every page.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment when you call `init_map()` `#map_canvas` doesn't exist(it will be loaded later).

Call the function in the `load`-callback:

```
$('#fatFooter').load('footer.html',function(){if(!window.map){init_map();}});
```

additionally add this to the begin of `init_map()` to avoid errors:

```
if(!document.getElementById('map_canvas')){return;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this has to do with the CSS file not playing nice or it cannot find something and defaults to the browser's default values.  When I checked this console log for your home page it contained no errors.  But when i checked other pages it threw an error that stated "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read property 'offsetWidth' of null' which is the maps width value in short.  This might be due to the 404 errors on all the pages except index.html which can be seen in your browsers Source tab.
 is showing a 404.  I would resolve these 404 errors and it should solve your problem.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script> is the  file it cannot find.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting up a race condition between the header/fatFooter/rightNav loading code and your callMap script. All those files are loaded asynchronously, so there's no guarantee which will finish first. In order to prevent your callMap script from running before the fatFooter is loaded, you'll need to use a callback instead of relying on the window's load event.

Since you're using it in two places, it might be easiest to wrap the body of init_map in a try/catch (to handle the case where the race condition doesn't go your way), and add a script block to the bottom of footer.html that calls init_map - but also wrap it in a try/catch. So either way, one try/catch block will trigger.

Another option is to create a custom event that is triggered by the loading of footer.html, and listened to by the callMap script.